# Pandas dataframe: Create additional column based on date columns comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Assuming I have the following dataset saved in a Pandas dataframe - note the last column [Status] is the column I'd like to create:

```
Department  Employee    Issue Date  Submission Date ***Status***
A   Joe 18/05/2014  25/06/2014  0
A   Joe 1/06/2014   28/06/2014  1
A   Joe 23/06/2014  30/06/2014  2
A   Mark    1/03/2015   13/03/2015  0
A   Mark    23/04/2015  15/04/2015  0
A   William 15/07/2016  30/07/2016  0
A   William 1/08/2016   23/08/2016  0
A   William 20/08/2016  19/08/2016  1
B   Liz 18/05/2014  7/06/2014   0
B   Liz 1/06/2014   15/06/2014  1
B   Liz 23/06/2014  16/06/2014  0
B   John    1/03/2015   13/03/2015  0
B   John    23/04/2015  15/04/2015  0
B   Alex    15/07/2016  30/07/2016  0
B   Alex    1/08/2016   23/08/2016  0
B   Alex    20/08/2016  19/08/2016  1
```

I'd like to create an additional column [Status] based on the following conditions:

1. For every unique [Department] & [Employee] combination (e.g. there are three rows corresponding to Joe in Department A), sort the [Issue Date] from oldest to newest
2. If the current row [Issue Date] is greater than **ALL** previous rows [Submission Date], then flag the [Status] with 0; else [Status] = no of times that [Issue Date] < [Submission Date]

As an example: for employee Joe in Department A. When [Issue Date] = '1/06/2014', the previous row's [Submission Date] is after the [Issue Date], therefore [Status] = 1 for row 2. Similarly, when [Issue Date] = '23/06/2014', row 1 & 2's [Submission Date]s are both after the [Issue Date], therefore [Status] = 2 for row 3. We need to perform this calculation for every unique combination of Department and Employee.

- Note: real dataset is not sorted nicely as the displayed example.

Answer (score 1):

This question was posted 6 months ago but hopefully my answer still provides some help.

First, import the libraries and make the dataframe:

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Make DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Department' : ['A']*8 + ['B']*8,
                   'Employee' : ['Joe']*3 +\
                                ['Mark']*2 +\
                                ['William']*3 +\
                                ['Liz']*3 +\
                                ['John']*2 +\
                                ['Alex']*3,
                   'Issue Date' : ['18/05/2014', '1/06/2014', '23/06/2014',
                                   '1/03/2015', '23/04/2015',
                                   '15/07/2016', '1/08/2016', '20/08/2016',
                                   '18/05/2014', '1/06/2014', '23/06/2014',
                                   '1/03/2015', '23/04/2015',
                                   '15/07/2016', '1/08/2016', '20/08/2016'],
                   'Submission Date' : ['25/06/2014', '28/06/2014', '30/06/2014',
                                        '13/03/2015', '15/04/2015',
                                        '30/07/2016', '23/08/2016', '19/08/2016',
                                        '7/06/2014', '15/06/2014', '16/06/2014',
                                        '13/03/2015', '15/04/2015',
                                        '30/07/2016', '23/08/2016', '19/08/2016']})
```

[image: df]

Second, convert Issue Date and Submission Date to datetime:

```
    # Convert 'Issue Date', 'Submission Date' to pd.datetime
df.loc[:, 'Issue Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'Issue Date'],
                                         dayfirst = True)
df.loc[:, 'Submission Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'Submission Date'],
                                              dayfirst = True)
```

Third, reset the index and sort the values by Department, Employee, and Issue Date:

```
# Reset index and sort_values by 'Department', 'Employee', 'Issue Date'
df.reset_index(drop = True).sort_values(by = ['Department',
                                              'Employee',
                                              'Issue Date'],
                                        inplace = True)
```

Fourth, group by Department, Employee; cumulative count the rows; insert into the originial df:

```
# Group by 'Department', 'Employee'; cumulative count rows; insert into original df
df.insert(df.shape[1],
          'grouped count',
          df.groupby(['Department',
                      'Employee']).cumcount())
```

[image: grouped count]

Fifth, create a no_issue and no_submission dataframe and merge them together on Department and Employee:

```
# Create df without 'Issue Date'
no_issue = df.drop('Issue Date', axis = 1)

# Create df without 'Submission Date'
no_submission = df.drop('Submission Date', axis = 1)

# Outer merge no_issue with no_submission on 'Department', 'Employee'
merged = no_issue.merge(no_submission,
                        how = 'outer',
                        on = ['Department',
                              'Employee'])
```

This duplicates the Submission Date by the number of Issue Dates per Department,Employee group

Here's what it looks like for Joe:

[image: merged]

Sixth, create a dataframe that only keeps rows where grouped count_x is less than grouped count_y, then sort by Department, Employee, and Issue Date:

```
# Create merged1 df that keeps only rows where 'grouped count_x' < 'grouped count_y';
# sort by 'Department', 'Employee', 'Issue Date
merged1 = merged[merged.loc[:, 'grouped count_x'] <
                 merged.loc[:, 'grouped count_y']].sort_values(by = ['Department',
                                                                     'Employee',
                                                                     'Issue Date'])
```

Seventh, insert the status column as a boolean where Issue Date is less than Submission Date:

```
# Insert 'Status' as a boolean when 'Issue Date' < 'Submission Date'
merged1.insert(merged.shape[1],
               'Status',
               merged1.loc[:, 'Issue Date'] < merged1.loc[:, 'Submission Date'])
```

Eighth, group by Department, Employee, and Issue Date, sum the Status, and reset the index:

```
# Group by 'Department', 'Employee', 'Issue Date' and sum 'Status'; reset index
merged1 = merged1.groupby(['Department',
                           'Employee',
                           'Issue Date']).agg({'Status' : np.sum}).reset_index()
```

This will return a dataframe with all the correct Statuses minus the minimum Issue Date for each Department, Employee group

[image: status]

Ninth, group the original merged dataframe by Department and Employee, find the minimum Issue Date, and reset the index:

```
# Group merged by 'Department', 'Employee' and find min 'Issue Date'; reset index
merged = merged.groupby(['Department',
                         'Employee']).agg({'Issue Date' : 'min'}).reset_index()
```

Tenth, concatenate merged1 with merged, fill the na with 0 (since the minimum Issue Date will always have a Status of 0) and sort by Department, Employee, and Issue Date:

```
# Concatenate merged with merged1; fill na with 0; sort by 'Department', 'Employee', 'Issue Date'
concatenated = pd.concat([merged1, merged]).fillna(0).sort_values(by = ['Department',
                                                                        'Employee',
                                                                        'Issue Date'])
```

Eleventh, inner merge the merged dataframe with the concatenated dataframe on Department, Employee, and Issue Date, then drop the grouped count:

```
# Merge concatenated with df; drop grouped count
final = df.merge(concatenated,
                 how = 'inner',
                 on = ['Department',
                       'Employee',
                       'Issue Date']).drop('grouped count',
                                           axis = 1)
```

Voila! Here is your final dataframe:

```
# Final df
final
```

[image: final]